# How to create a folder and save more than one files to that folder in android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Im using the code as shown bellow for saving a jpg file to sdcard on a button click.

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
            try 
            {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                mMergedLayersBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

for saving the image to a folder, I rewrite the code as shown bellow

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
            //Create Folder
              File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/draw/Images");
              folder.mkdirs();

              //Save the path as a string value
              String extStorageDirectory = folder.toString();

              //Create New file and name it draw.jpg
              File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "draw.jpg");
              try 
                {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    mMergedLayersBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Now its rewriting the image when I am click the save button second time. I want to save the whole image that im saving to a folder. I don't know how to change my code for this requirement. If anyone know about this, please help me..

Comment: Change this: `"draw.jpg"` to `String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()` in second method for new file name.

Comment: Thanks Harry Joy.... I got it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have hardcoded the name of the image as `"draw.jpg"`, each time your image gets overwritten. So instead of hardcoding provide a dynamic name.

For Example, instead of,

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "draw.jpg");
```

try

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, System.currentTimeMillis()+"draw.jpg");
```